# Backing up NAS to NAS

Tags: backup, sync

I am pretty new to Ubuntu. I have yet to really use it's full functionality (ie command lines). I'm using an older laptop to set it up to run as a media server using Plex. I was hoping to use it to sync my 2 WD My Book Live NAS drives automatically. One NAS drive is used to store all of my media the other is to backup that same media.

So my setup is basically this Ubuntu 12.04. The laptop will be directly wired to the router that the 2 NAS drives are connected to. I would like to have it sync at least once a week, but preferably once a day (each day being a different folder/folders). In addition my Plex media will be stored on a normal WD external plugged directly into the laptop. I would also like this to be sync'd daily. Is this a complicated setup for the syncing? Where do I begin?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two things you can look at in regards to backup/sync.

1. Backup / Archive - This will be a synced backup that will be
   something you can recover from the historical data.
2. Sync - Same files on both locations similar to dropbox

If you are looking to do a backup / archive sync, there is a protocol "rsync" that is fairly handy in linux environments. http://rsync.samba.org/

If you are looking for something like the dropbox type sync, bittorrent came out with software that make it easy to have your own sync'd environment. http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html

The btsync can be a little process intense depending on what you mean by older laptop.